# ZIP Archive Created Within ZIP Archive

Tags: python-2.7, zip

I recently wrote a python script to select certain files within a directory and save them to a new archive within that directory. The script works with the exception that it creates a duplicate archive within the new archive. I think it has something to do with the arcname I used and the loop but I'm really not sure. As I'm sure is obvious by looking at my code I am a beginner so I am sure there is plenty of room for improvement here. Any ideas as to where the problem is? Also if you have any suggestions for improving the code I'm all ears.

```
    import os,arcpy,zipfile

inputfc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) # User Inputs Feature Class Path 

desc = arcpy.Describe(inputfc)

fcname = desc.basename

zname =  fcname + ".zip"

gpath = os.path.dirname(inputfc)

zpath = os.path.join(gpath,zname)

zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(zpath, "w")

for f in os.listdir(gpath):
    fpath = os.path.join(gpath, f)
    if f.startswith(fcname):
        zfile.write(fpath,f,compress_type = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)


zfile.close()
```

[image: these are the files within the new archive]

Edit: After aruisdante answered my question I decided to just change the zname variable to

zname =  "zip" + fcname + ".zip" #ugly but it worked thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
zfile = zipfile.ZipFile(zpath, "w")
```

Creates a new Zip file at `zpath`

```
for f in os.listdir(gpath):
```

Iterates through all of the files at `gpath`. Since `gpath` is also the root of `zpath`, then the zip file you just created will be one of the files in `gpath`. So it gets included in the archive. You will need to exclude it:

```
for f in (filename for filename in os.listdir(gpath) if filename != zname):
```

Comment: ahhh ok would it also be possible to not name the archive* after the fcname thus it wouldn't get included?